# Couldn't "ni" particle be used in this example?

Tags: grammar, particles, time

I'm a total newbie learning japanese as you will see, so please be patient with me. I have this sentence from my textbook:

> Shiken no toki jisho o minai de kudasai!

Because it was a new lesson, I didn't know what were the meanings for `shiken` or `toki`, so I've just assumed that `toki` is an adjective for `jisho` and after I've looked up the words in the vocabulary section, it suddenly became really strange for me to think about how am I going to translate it.

So, my question is: Couldn't `ni` particle be used there between `toki` and `jisho`:

> Shiken no toki **ni** jisho o minai de kudasai!

to mark the time in which the action takes place?
I know the sentence is obvious for someone who does know japanese, but I'm only asking this for grammar purposes.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I found out that in the textbook it is stated something about the `ni` particle in combination with nouns like `mainichi`. It's briefly explained that the `ni` particle cannot be used when associated with relative time [`mainichi` in book's example]  (I hope I translated it well, the textbook is not in english). I guess this could answer my question, but I'll gladly wait for anyone who's more knowledgeable to answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use **ni** there.

> Shiken no toki **ni** jisho o minai de kudasai!

This sentence is grammatically correct and actually used. A web site
https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/98363.html explains the reason:

> 2)「時間の名詞」が複合の形をとる場合、例えば、「おととい」という時間を表わす名詞にさらに「朝」という時間を表わす名詞がついて「おとといの朝」などという形になる場合はやや複雑で、「あしたの昼、テニスをします」と助詞を伴わずにも使われますし，「あしたの昼に、テニスをします」と助詞を伴っても使われます。この二つの文の場合ですが，意味的には実は違いがありません。「に」を伴うことによって「強調」を表わしていると思われる傾向にあるようですが，この場合の「に」は「格助詞」として「より顕著な副詞表現に属することを表わしている」に過ぎません。

I understand the example

> Shiken no toki **ni**

is

> 「時間の名詞」が複合の形をとる場合

.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that something like "ashita ni" would be 100% grammatically correct and more formal than just "ashita". Is that what you meant to imply?

Comment: @Leebo, yes, your understanding is right.

Comment: I have to disagree with that then.

Comment: @akawaguc 1. Could you expand on that? Do you mean _theoretically_ correct, but never used (because, say, `明日には` is used showing that `明日に` is grammatically correct but simply never used) ; or do you mean `明日に` is fine, commonly used in formal contexts, and `明日` is just the more informal equivalent ? --- 2. If the latter, could you give any example sentences with `明日に` (outside of constructs such as `になる` `にする` etc of course) ?

Comment: @Leebo, thank you for your comments.
I reconsidered the change of formality by adding "ni", removed it in my answer and added a quotation from a 3rd party's website to show examples of "ni".

Comment: @desseim,
See my above answer I have just updated.

Comment: @akawaguc in the two examples listed (7時 and ３月１５日), those are both specific times, where as things like きょう, あす and あさって are relative times. That was what I was objecting to, about applying に to relative times.

Comment: @Leebo, thank you again for your pointing out that. You are right.
I re-editted my answer.